# eval command not working in ssh

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

```
read -d '' String <<"EOF"
ls
EOF
```

The above command basically assigns `ls` into the variable `String`. Now i use this

```
sshpass -p 'Ku99123' ssh -t  kuhl@adf-sc-101.i.e.ibi.com 'cd /var/www/nginx/network ; eval $String && exec bash -l'
```

In the above command, i am trying to execute the command written in variable `String`. But `eval` is not working here. If i write simple `ls` command instead of `eval $String`, it works.

What syntactical or logical crime am i doing here?

Comment: Are you sure it is `ls`, not `ls\n`?

Comment: @MadPhysicist , how do i verify that?

Comment: No need. That is not the problem. $String is interpreted literally because you are using single quotes.

Comment: @Barmar, how will even i know that this is related to single and double quotes. AT least you could have commented rather than marking as duplicate.

Comment: Since I linked it to a question about single and double quotes, you'll know that this is the problem. `$String` isn't expanded inside single quotes.

Comment: @Diffy the link is displayed on top only.